Seasons on ringworld
I'm working on a planet-sized orbiting a star, with the ring perpendicular to it's ecliptic plane. This means that throughout the year it receives more or less sunlight based on it's angle to it's star, with "winter" when the surface is close to parallel with the light rays and "summer" when the surface is close to perpendicular. ie
Summer:
Winter: 
I've calculated the change in solar radiation the ring will receive throughout the year, from there how would I go about calculating surface air temperatures?

How much of the solar radiation is used to maintain the orbit?

you would also have a second short winter when the rings starts occluding its own inner surface with shadow. unless the ring is thin enough for rapid heat transmission through it.

Note that if it's perpendicular the night cycle flips by 12 hours at each solstice.  Any reason not to make the tilt smaller?

@AntonSherwood I don't think thare is any way around having them flip

@John Can't avoid some deviation from mean time, but if the tilt is lower you get a more moderate analemma. — To answer myself, lower tilt means shorter daylight most of the year, I think.

Once you calculate the solar irradiance upon your orbital ring, you also need to consider the albedo and emissivity of your world.  The temperature of your world will be related to the solar radiation that is not reflected away (by albedo), and is absorbed by the materials from which your world is made.
As objects absorb thermal energy, they become hotter, but as they become hotter, they emit more heat, proportional to the emissivity of the object and the fourth power of the temperature, so as the temperature of an object rises, it will emit more heat.
Heat capacity  of the materials of your world becomes important because different materials can absorb different amounts of thermal energy per degree of temperature increase... and if your materials change state between solid, liquid or gas, heats of fusion and/or vaporisation can become important, as these absorb or emit energy without a change in temperature.  These factors affect the time it takes for the incoming heat to make your world hotter, so the faster the world rotates, the lower the temperature changes will be.
Ultimately, temperature becomes a balance between linear heat input, heat capacity, and the fourth-power heat output.  Since we don't know the albedo, emissivity, heat capacity of your world or rotational speed, nor its primary's heat output or distance, we can't say what its temperature would  be at any particular distance.
